# How to access GitHub Packages (Maven Repository) of public artefacts?

Tags: maven, gradle, github-packages

Has anyone an idea how to access GitHub Packages (Maven Repository) of public artefacts?

In my case, there is an artefact published in a public repository: https://github.com/viascom/spring-boot-starter-maintenance/packages/1424240

I know that I can access it like this:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url = uri("https://maven.pkg.github.com/viascom/*")
        credentials {
            username = project.findProperty("gpr.user") ?: System.getenv("GITHUB_ACTOR")
            password = project.findProperty("gpr.token") ?: System.getenv("GITHUB_TOKEN")
        }
    }
}
```

and having the corresponding username and token placed in the properties.gradle.

But what I actually want to achieve is something easy to share with others maybe not even having to have a registered GitHub Account as an alternative for the Maven Central releases.

So my question is, **is there a way to define GitHub Packages as a repository for any organization? And if not then organization only dependent, instead of specifying it till the project?**

And also interesting, is there a way to access those artefacts without providing a username and pasword/token?

Thanks for any hints in advance!

Cheers

Comment: There is only one decision: Either use Github and you have to use GitHub access because GitHub packages are limited based on access... so it's not alternative to Maven Central because Maven Central can be accessed without access token or any other kind of credentials. From my point of view GitHub packages are not an alternative to Central... Use central....because GitHub packages a kind of vendor lock in...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Gradle plugin of mine ([magik](https://github.com/elect86/magik), I was exactly in your shoes) to easier the consumption of artifacts, you can either:

- have a Github repository acting as a Maven repository
- or publish on Github Packages and easier the consumption for Gradle
  clients